# Call a SOAP Service using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, soap

As the title suggests, I'm trying to figure out how to call a soap service using JavaScript. The SOAP Service is being run on Tomcat on my local machine. Along with accessing the SOAP service, I can also download/access/read the WSDL very easily.

I've been hitting my head against the wall for days now with this problem. While researching, I'm come across short examples, but none are comprehensive and detail how to accomplish this from start to end. That, or I've found a solution but it only works for IE or Mozilla.

Any ideas how to call a SOAP web service using Javascript (on major browsers)? Thanks!

(PS: I'm also using jquery. So if you want to accomplish this using some slick jquery tool, please feel free to suggest it)

Comment: Adding just a bit more detail that may help you. I'm trying to send and recall data using a service without reloading the current webpage (so I'm using the service in the background). The web service is there to negotiate and work with a database. I may be doing this wrong- if so, how should I be doing this?

Answer (score 1):

SOAP is just XML so it should be possible to do this, however I'm not aware of any existing SOAP Clients written in JS

A more common method would probably be:

1. JavaScript initiates an XHR object which calls to a server-side AJAX helper using either GET/POST parameters, or a JSON encoded object
2. AJAX helper makes the call to either a Database or Web Service, as appropriate, and outputs required data object(s) as either JSON or XML
3. JavaScript parses response body (JSON or XML) and takes required action using specified data.

This has a couple of advantages over trying to call WebServices directly from JavaScript:

- SOAP XML can be quite complex, which means more data to transfer to and from the client, which may be a slow connection. JSON in particular, but also an XML schema that just has the required data would be a much more economical on data usage
- If the WebService requires any kind of authentication the authentication details will be exposed to all visitors.
- Web Services are generally used for to standardise communications between separate systems, rather than for communication between the front and back end components of the same Application/Site.